# Android App crashes after proguard obfuscation using Ionic3

Tags: java, android, ionic3, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

I have run **proguard tool on my ionic v3 app to obfuscate**. For that I have used [cordova-plugin-proguard](https://github.com/greybax/cordova-plugin-proguard), When I generate signed apk with "Proguard Obfuscation" and then install the apk file, it is crashing.

**NOTE:** I haven't deployed proguard Obfuscation (mapping.txt) in play store.

So I don't know what to do now.

Here is my **Build.gradle** file:

```
 buildTypes {
            debug {
                debuggable true
                minifyEnabled false
                useProguard true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                debuggable false
                useProguard true
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

Also **proguard-project.txt** file:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
-keepclassmembers class android.webkit.WebView {
   public *;
}

-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar

# Using Google's License Verification Library 
-keep class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Specifies to write out some more information during processing. 
# If the program terminates with an exception, this option will print out the entire stack trace, instead of just the exception message.
-verbose

# Annotations are represented by attributes that have no direct effect on the execution of the code. 
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}

# These options let obfuscated applications or libraries produce stack traces that can still be deciphered later on 
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Enable proguard with Cordova
-keep class org.apache.cordova.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin

-keep class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader { java.lang.ClassLoader sClassLoader; }

-keep class org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.ResumeCallback { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }
-keep class org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine { org.apache.cordova.PluginManager pluginManager; }

-dontnote org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe

-keep class com.worklight.androidgap.push.** { *; }
-keep class com.worklight.wlclient.push.** { *; }

# Enable proguard with Google libs
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# apache.http
-optimizations !class/merging/vertical*,!class/merging/horizontal*,!code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!code/allocation/variable

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }
-dontwarn net.sqlcipher.**

-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Remove debug logs in release build
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}

# These classes contain references to external jars which are not included in the default MobileFirst project.
-dontwarn com.worklight.common.internal.WLTrusteerInternal*
-dontwarn com.worklight.jsonstore.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.*
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.push.GCMIntentService
-dontwarn com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
-dontwarn android.net.http.*

# These clases contain references to cordova webView
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.** {*; }
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.*
```

Another one **proguard-rules.pro** file:

```
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /usr/share/android-studio/data/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
#-optimizations code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,! class/merging/*,!method/inlining/*
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*
#,!class/merging/*


-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

#---------------Begin: proguard configuration for support library  ----------

-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version. We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.example.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

-keep class com.github.browep.MainActivity



-keep class org.apache.cordova.** {
    *;
}

-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin


-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.client.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.cookie.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.message.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.util.** { *; }

# These clases contain references to cordova webView
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.** {*; }
-keep class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.*
```

I hope it will help.
Thanks in advance!